# Dynamically selecting to which class to load in a Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Suppose that I have 2 classes, `WebLogicEndPoint.class` and `WebSphereEndpoint.class`, inside my `Java` web application.

When I will deploy this application in `WebLogic` or `Websphere`, I need to load the specific class depending on server and have to avoid the other one, otherwise if both classes are loaded deployment will fail.

Kindly give me some suggestion to achieve this.

Comment: When you say load the specific class, you mean retrieve an instance of it and use it, correct? Or you want to avoid that one of the classes be loaded by the container?

Comment: If it is an option, Spring framework is great at dynamic configuration.

Comment: @serge: OP is using [java-ee] and you're recommending a Spring solution..? Just recommend Java EE's own CDI. Or are you still from decade-old J2EE era when CDI didn't exist?

Comment: @BalusC: I simply better know Spring than Java EE CDI. For the first, I could say how to use different profiles so that a simple environment variable allows the application to choose the correct class while for the latter I only know that it exists :-( . And that's one of the reasons why I just posted a comment and not a full answer...

Comment: @BalusC, in order to solve OP's problem I thought of a `@WebServletContextListener`, on `contextInitialized` would check the  server info from the `ServletContext` and would load the endpoint class accordingly. But using the CDI approach, what could be the solution? Create a `Producer` that would check the application server type and return the correct endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Factory pattern to load the desired class according to the environment.